# HTTPS Settings is disabled in freshly started artifactory-cpp-ce - how do I enable it?

Tags: artifactory

Following the [instructions for starting Artifactory Community Edition](https://conan.io/downloads.html) I can launch an artifactory instance like this:

```
docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-cpp-ce:latest
```

Afterwards I can log in as admin in the web UI on http://localhost:8082. The instructions recommend setting up an inverse proxy and the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings) says "To configure a reverse proxy, in the Administration module, select Artifactory  | HTTP Settings". Unfortunately this is not possible as the "HTTP Settings" menu item is grayed out:

[image: Screenshot of Artifactory Administration Pane]

It is unclear to me why it is grayed out and what I can do to enable it. The tooltip just says [object Object] which seems like a bug, but it is also possible that this feature is just not part of the Community Edition of Artifactory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP Settings is not supported in Artifactory Community Edition.
That said, you may want to check out the free-tier option for testing this configuration and additional features at: https://jfrog.com/start-free

Regarding the [object Object]  tooltip message, I want to thank you for the screenshot as it helped clarifying the issue. I had taken note of it and will open a task for fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - will the issue be visible in the public issue tracker. I do not see it in https://www.jfrog.com/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20RTFACT%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC

Comment: A fix should be available from Artifactory 7.41.x and above. The linked ticket is not synced in this specific tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if there is a `no_proxy` environment variable set which could influence the HTTP settings availability (a bit as in [issue 67](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/67#issuecomment-378616990=)).

But also consider deploying Artifactory in a Kubernetes environment (included with any Docker Desktop setup), using the [`jfrog/charts` `artifactory-cpp-ce`](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory-cpp-ce).

That would come directly with:

> - JFrog Artifactory CE for C++
> - an optional Nginx server
> - an optional PostgreSQL Database
> - and optionally expose Artifactory with Ingress Ingress documentation

Comment: no_proxy is not set in the environment