# Artifactory CE Edition Configure HTTPS

Tags: nginx, artifactory

I have install a free Artifactory Server (Community Edition and edition license 7.29.8 rev 72908900 )

So when I can't configure url HTTP or HTTPS url

When I launch Artifactory web In http (Administration ==> General ==> HTTP Setting) are unavailable.

I have install NGINX server and I can't launch artifactory in https.

I use the same VM to NGIX and Artifactory.

I have found this documentation: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings & https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings & https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX

My configuration nginx server:

```
## add ssl entries when https has been set in config

##ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt;

ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/domain.key;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;

##ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

## server configuration

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    listen 8080;
    
    server_name <Server_Name>;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {

        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;

    }

    ## Application specific logs

    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/<Server_Name>-access.log timing;

    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/<Server_Name>-error.log;

    rewrite ^/$ /ui/ redirect;

    rewrite ^/ui$ /ui/ redirect;

    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {

    proxy_read_timeout  2400s;

    proxy_pass_header   Server;

    proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_buffers 40 128k;

    proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;

    proxy_pass          https://<Artifactory_IP>:8082;

    proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;

    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
    location ~ ^/artifactory/ {

            proxy_pass    https://<Artifactory_IP>:8081;

        }

    }

}
```

And all are KO

Can you help me?

I juste want to launch artifactory in https://x.x.x.x:80802 for example

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Settings is not supported in Artifactory Community Edition. That said, you may want to check out the free-tier option for testing this configuration and additional features at: https://jfrog.com/start-free

similar query: [HTTPS Settings is disabled in freshly started artifactory-cpp-ce - how do I enable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72613347/https-settings-is-disabled-in-freshly-started-artifactory-cpp-ce-how-do-i-enab/72614175#72614175)

Comment: Hello Thanks for your feedback, I can't configure HTTPS without this option?

Comment: Via the UI, you cannot. However, You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67216333/how-to-configure-jfrog-artifactory-web-interface-to-use-https-rather-than-http